# Android emulator doesn't take land layout

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape

I'm trying to make layout to work on tablets and also on landscape mode.

I've created `layout-sw600dp` and `layout-sw600dp-land` folders but when I try to run the app with the emulator it doesn't use correct layout  (from `layout-sw600dp-land` folder).

I'm not using any kind of config in `AndroidManifest.xml` which wouldn't allow the landscape mode. The emulator has the latest version of android

Comment: Can you determine which exactly layout is being used? (I assume you are using correct screen size in emulator - try 10" tablet in case you are not)

Comment: I've tried with 7" and 10" tablets because I have two layout folders, one for 600dp and other for 720dp but neither one worked